# switch case in php multiple words to one case

Tags: php

```
<?php

$rank = $_POST['person'];
$name = $_POST['fname'];

switch ($rank){
    case 'MR':
        echo "Hi Mr ".$name." Wellcome To My Website";
        break;
    case 'dr':
        echo "Hi Dr ".$name." Wellcome To My Website";
        break;
    case 'miss':
            echo "Hi Miss ".$name." Wellcome To My Website";
            break;  
    case 'Prof':
            echo "Hi Prof ".$name." Wellcome To My Website";
            break;
    defualt:
        echo "Wrong";   .
```

i want to add multiple keywords to one case. like this some one can enter Mr or MR or mr php is case sensitive language. I want to add all those mr,Mr,MR words to one case how can i do it.

Comment: Why don't you use: `echo "Hi" . $rank . " " . $name . " Wellcome To My Website";` ?? Also make sure you HTML escape the inputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
switch ($rank){
  case 'MR':
  case 'mr':
  case 'Mr':
    echo "Hi Mr ".$name." Wellcome To My Website";
    break;
  case 'dr':
    echo "Hi Dr ".$name." Wellcome To My Website";
    break;
  case 'miss':
        echo "Hi Miss ".$name." Wellcome To My Website";
        break;  
  case 'Prof':
        echo "Hi Prof ".$name." Wellcome To My Website";
        break;
  default:
    echo "Wrong";
```

That will do what you want, in regards to multiple cases to one event.  But, I would suggest instead that you change your switch statement to something like this:

```
switch (strtolower($rank)){
```

And then only check the lowercase values.